# Punch a Transparent hole in my semi Black Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to create a Black screen with a transparent Hole in the middle of the screen. Here is what i have tried.

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    Paint myPaint = new Paint();
    myPaint.setColor(0xC0000000);
    canvas.drawRect(mBlackRect, myPaint);

    myPaint = new Paint();
    myPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    myPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    canvas.drawRect(mTransparentRect, myPaint);
}
```

The second paint, shows black color instead of transparent. How can i punch a transparent hole in MY SemiBlack Canvas?

Answer (score 1):

you didn't save the canvas, try the code below

```
Paint myPaint = new Paint();
    int sc = canvas.saveLayer(mBlackRect.left, mBlackRect.top,
            mBlackRect.right, mBlackRect.bottom, myPaint,
            Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
    myPaint.setColor(0xC0000000);
    canvas.drawRect(mBlackRect, myPaint);

    myPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    myPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    canvas.drawRect(mTransparentRect, myPaint);
    myPaint.setXfermode(null);
    canvas.restoreToCount(sc);
```

Comment: From Android documentation: Canvas.saveLayer() - "this method is very expensive, incurring more than double rendering cost for contained content. Avoid using this method, especially if the bounds provided are large"

Comment: @BladeCoder that is because you are using xfermode, you can also draw 4 opaque rect around the hole.

Comment: @rainash this shows a black screen with a red square at top ... wtf

Comment: @MuhammadUmar red square? your backgound color is red? at top? check your mTransparentRect , I change the color from semiblack to black so you get a black screen, I have edited the answer and run the code, that works

Answer (score 0):

You can not really "punch" a hole by "removing pixels" from something already drawn, at least not with a hardware layer. And if you use a software layer, it will be bad for performance.

What you want to do is draw your shape with an alpha mask applied to your paint. A mask will prevent some parts of the shape to be drawn on the canvas, like cutting a piece of paper and stick it on a wall before spreading the painting.

To apply an alpha mask to your paint, you first need to create a bitmap containing the "hole" shape (programmatically or by loading a custom image from resources), then create a `BitmapShader` from this bitmap with the proper Xfermode (depending if you want the transparent part in your mask bitmap to be cut out or the non-transparent part) and finally apply this shader to your paint before drawing the semitransparent rectangle or anything you want.

Be careful with performance: only create the Paint object once (do **not** allocate any object in onDraw() because this method gets called up to 60 times per second on the UI thread), and recreate the alpha mask bitmap only when the bounds of your View/Drawable change (if its dimensions depend on the View dimensions of course, otherwise you just create it once).

I'm sorry if I don't have time to give you ready-to-use code but I think you should find plenty of information about the technique I just described and you can start experimenting and figuring out the solution by yourself which is more rewarding I think ;)